# What Rust Crates are allowed in Solana Smart contract?

Tags: solana-program, rust, program

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement a federated averaging function on solana. But im not sure if I can use the crates that would allow me to do that.

Here are the crates i wanna use.

[Numpy](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/index.html)

[PyO3](https://pyo3.rs/v0.12.3/index.html)

Can i use these 2 crates on a solana program?

Comment: are you using seahorse-lang for it or rust ?

Comment: If you want to use Numpy you should try the [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/) crate. I don't know if it works in Solana but I'm optimistic

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those will run in a Solana smart contract, since the Solana VM doesn't have python installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do ML operations on chain or run inference using a model, it's better to use [seahorse-lang](https://seahorse-lang.org/). Relevant example is [sea-nn](https://twitter.com/wireless_anon/status/1561664190590623744).